# After exiting shell editor cannot reach docker nodes anymore

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-machine, hyper-v

I created three nodes and named as node1, node2, node3 using the following docker command:

```
docker-machine create -d hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "Primary Virtual Switch" node1
```

I also followed the steps described here: https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/hyper-v/

Now my problem is that if I close cmd or any other shell editor I can no longer reach the nodes:

[image]

I checked, what happen with Hyper-V Manager and it seems that the nodes are active and still running:

[image]

Trying to start the nodes I get the following message:

`docker-machine start node1`

`Starting "node1"...`

`exit status 1`

**So the question is pretty much obvious, whats wrong in here? Am I doing something wrong? What could be a possible work around or even a specific solution?**

Comment: `docker start` is for starting containers (hence the error message). It has nothing to do with the virtual machines created by `docker-machine`.

Comment: @larsks yeah you are right, I meant docker-machine start, thanks for letting me know.